# Calculate Percentage of each sub category in R Programming?

Tags: r, categorical-data, data-transformation, dataset

I have the following dataset:

```
      Year Type_code Age_group                                           Type Total 
1     2001    Causes      0-14                                   Love Affairs     1
2     2001    Causes      0-14                        Other Prolonged Illness     1
3     2001    Causes      0-14                         Failure in Examination     1
4     2001    Causes     15-29                        Other Prolonged Illness     8
5     2001    Causes     15-29                                Family Problems     5
6     2001    Causes     15-29                         Failure in Examination     2
7     2001    Causes     15-29                        Insanity/Mental Illness     2
8     2001    Causes     15-29                        Other Prolonged Illness     3
9     2001    Causes     15-29                                Family Problems     3
10    2001    Causes     15-29                                   Love Affairs     3
11    2001    Causes     15-29                        Insanity/Mental Illness     2
143   2005    Causes     15-29                           Death of Dear Person     1
144   2005    Causes     30-44                                Family Problems     1
145   2005    Causes     30-44                        Insanity/Mental Illness     2
```

And so on. I need to find the "percentage" of deaths (Total column) by cause (Type) in each year (Year). How can I do this in R? Also, I am a beginner so I also need help with hypothesis testing. My null hypothesis is that "More than 20% of people commit suicide because of Family Problems each year." How can I do this?

I have referred to [this](https://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab-express/1/help-and-how-to/modeling-statistics/regression/supporting-topics/regression-models/using-the-t-value-to-determine-whether-to-reject-the-null-hypothesis/), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27134516/summarizing-by-subgroup-percentage-in-r), [this](https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/achoulde/94842/lectures/lecture07/lecture07-94842.html), and [this](https://quantpalaeo.wordpress.com/2018/04/29/how-to-calculate-percent-from-counts-in-r/) but I got overwhelmed and now I am really confused. Please help. I am a noob and this is for my school project!

**For example, 5% of people commited sucide in 2001 because of Love Affairs.**

I think I do understand the procedure - first, find the percentage of deaths by Family Problems in each year, and then take its average over each year and test if this average is greater than 20 percent or not.

Comment: I do not think it can be done without having individuals being entered individually. Otherwise, all we can do is show some vague association between age groups and "causes" in each age group, but not how many people had both "love affairs" and "committed suicide" in any age group.

Comment: welcome to the site. ! As this is a programming question, it belongs on stackoverflow - it is off-topic here....

Comment: @RobertLong I have to disagree (in part). When OP says "I need to find the "percentage" of deaths (Total column) by cause (Type) in each year (Year). How can I do this in R?", that is a programming question that would be on topic at Stack Overflow, and alone would be off topic here. However, because the OP also says "so I also need help with hypothesis testing. My null hypothesis is that "More than 20% of people commit suicide because of Family Problems each year." How can I do this?", if posted to Stack Overflow, the question would likely be migrated here.

Comment: @RobertLong **tl;dr** Because the OP needs help with understanding hypothesis testing in addition to their programming difficulties, I would be inclined to consider it **off topic at Stack Overflow**, and potentially on topic here.

Comment: @Carl I think all of them are deaths from suicide if I read the question correctly.

Comment: It would help if you can summarise what the links you have put told you and why you are confused and also tell us what statistical techniques you have thought of so someone can point you in a good direction.

Comment: @duckmayr fair enough ! It was not me who voted to close anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Hypothesis Testing

H​0: Each year, ​more than 30% ​of people commit suicide because of ​Family Problems.

H​1: ​Less than 30%​ of people commit suicide because of Family Problems.

### Step 1: Group dataset by year, type and total number of suicides by that type.

Find total number of deaths by cause

```
​library​(plyr)
​groupColumns = c(​"Year"​,​"Type"​)
​dataColumns = c(​"Total"​)
​res <- ddply(hyp_died, groupColumns, ​function​(x) colSums(x[dataColumns]))
```

### Step 2: Find total number of suicides per year.

Total number of suicides per year

```
​hyp_grouped <- aggregate(res$Total, by=list(Category=res$Year), FUN=sum)
```

### Step 3: Add this data to the ​res​ data frame.

Add total number of deaths in year to res
​

```
res <- res %>%
rowwise %>%
do({
result = as_data_frame(.)
  result$TotalDied = hyp_grouped[hyp_grouped$Category == result$Year, 2​]
  result
})
```

### Step 4: Find percentage cause of each suicide.

Find percentage cause of each suicide.
​

```
res <- res %>%
 rowwise %>%
 do({
result = as_data_frame(.)
result$Percentage = (result$Total/(result$TotalDied))*​100
 result
 })
```

### Step 5: Find percentage of suicides by Family Problems each year.

Find percentage of suicides by Family Problems each year.

```
​hyp_familyProblems <- res %>%
 filter(Total > ​0​, Type == ​"Family Problems"​)

Year Type   Total    Total Died  Percentage
2001 Family Problems 24162 74067 32.62182
2002 Family Problems 25085 75891 33.05399
2003 Family Problems 26308 78419 33.54799
2004 Family Problems 25531 78690 32.44504
2005 Family Problems 25441 77022 33.03082
2006 Family Problems 30771 85675 35.91596
2007 Family Problems 29238 84575 34.5705
2008 Family Problems 29777 86225 34.53407
2009 Family Problems 30082 85364 35.23968
2010 Family Problems 31856 90476 35.20934
2011 Family Problems 32909 89927 36.59524
2012 Family Problems 30792 81524 37.77047
```

### Step 6: Test the hypothesis.

Use t-test to find out if hypothesis is true or not

```
​summary(hyp_familyProblems$Percentage)
​t.test(hyp_familyProblems$Percentage, mu = 30, alternative = "less")
```

This will print the following output:

```
> summary(hyp_familyProblems$Percentage)
Min. 1st Qu. Median Mean 3rd Qu. Max.
32.45 33.05 34.55 34.54 35.41 37.77
> t.test(hyp_familyProblems$Percentage, mu = 30, alternative = "less")
One Sample t-test
data: hyp_familyProblems$Percentage
t = 9.3733, df = 11, p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: true mean is less than 30
95 percent confidence interval:
-Inf 35.4153
sample estimates:
mean of x
34.54458
```

## Hypothesis Conclusion

The ​p-value is 1​, which clearly suggests that our hypothesis is true with ​95%
confidence.

In other words, ​**We are 95% confident that more than 30% of people commit suicide
because of family problems each year**.